# Take String (Ex. "Car") and turn it into Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the string representation of a class that I want to call. The class already exists.

```
klass = "Broseph"
Class.new(Broseph)
# => #<Class:0x007f9f0c1cc8b8>
Class.new("Broseph")
# => TypeError: superclass must be a Class (String given)
```

How can turn the string into a class? How can I call a class method on a class that I have represented as a string? I will also need to pass arguments to that class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `const_get`:

```
klazz = Object.const_get('Broseph')
```

Then call methods on `klazz` like:

```
klazz.some_method # when you know the method is fixed
klazz.send('some_method') # when the method also is stored in a string
```